# Project is not running on android emulator

Tags: android-studio, react-native, android-emulator, frontend

I've been trying to run my project on the android emulator for a while now but no results.

Posted several times and tried to re-link libraries. Below is the exposed error

```
What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':expo-react-native-adapter'.
Project with path ':expo-core' could not be found in project ':expo-react-native-adapter'.

Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 5.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/4.10.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
```